# Is it possible to trigger ReactJs component re-render when simply change state object property?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJs and I ran into some question when trying out the `useState` and `useContext` hook. It seems the re-rendering will only happen if there is reference change rather than value change. Take the bellowing code for example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4gw3h1

```
class Counter {
   count: number;
   constructor(count: number) {
     this.count = count;
   }
   
   increase() {
     this.count += 1;
   }
}

export const CountComponent : FC = (props) => {
   //const [count, setCount] = useState(0); // work
   //const [count, setCount] = useState({0}); // work
   const [counter] = useState(new Counter(0)); // not work

   const doAdd = () => {
      counter.increase();
      console.log(counter.count);
   }
    
   // this will not actually re-render 
   return (<div>{counter.count}<button onClick={doAdd}>+</button></div>);
}
```

As you click the button, the count has increased yet the value rendered isn't updated. Am I missing anything there? And is there a way to have the component monitor the state object property change?

**EDIT**

I think I have confused people with intention of the question. Consider a more complicated use case where I have a complex state object. Pardon me with the psuedocode:

```
class Cargo {
    orders: Map<string, Products[]>;
    totalValue: number;
    totalNumber: number;

    addProduct(product: Product) {
      // ignore the null check here.
      this.orders.get(product.owner).push(product);
      this.totalValue += product.value;
      this.totalNumber ++;
    }
}

class Product {
   owner: string;
   name: string;
   value: number;
}

const CargoContext = createContext(new Cargo());

const CargoContext = createContext({... new Cargo(), setTotalValue, setTotalNumber});

// lost the OO
const {orders, totalValue, totalNumber, setTotalValue, setTotalNumber} = useContext(CargoContext);

const doAdd = (product: Product) => {
   orders.get(product.owner); 
   setTotalValue(product.value);
   setTotalNumber(totalNumber + 1);
}
```

When creating a context this way, I won't be able to update the state actually. The only way to make it work from what I read is to deconstruct the Cargo object and passing the property and dispatcher. But that lose the object-oriented `Cargo` and `addProduct` interface. How to deal with this case more gracefully?

Comment: You're not using state correctly. How does React know state has changed if you don't tell it that state has changed? You need to use the `setCounter` function. The update function does more than just change the state value. It asks React to compare the old and new values and schedule a render if they're different. The comparison is also a shallow compare, so since your state is an object, the ref needs to change, not just a value inside it.

Comment: `useState` returns 2 things - its current value and the updater function. You should destructure with `const [counter, setCounter] ...` and use `setCounter` to update that state, which will trigger a re-render

Comment: The good news is its actually easier than you've made it! The `Counter` class is unnecessary. Just give `useState` the initial value of `0` and you're good to go! (while also following the suggested commented above)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I realized I am not presenting my intention precisely. I have edited my question.

Comment: @JMadelaine You are absolutely correct. Is there a way to do deep comparison, or watch/subscribe to certain properties in the state object is the question I have. Right now, the only thing I can think of is adding a `flag` (feels hacky tho) to the state object to force the re-render and allow me to pass the OO object without deconstructing it.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to do that? What is your use case? Surely you can use React the intended way and achieve what you want? Why do you need to pass the counter as an object? And if it really does need to be an object, then surely storing it in state is the wrong thing. You probably want to pass its count property as a prop to the child component.

Comment: I believe your issue is that you are writing functional code but trying to use an OO paradigm. Just stick with the functional approach. Also, your context needs a provider, which you currently don't have. Your provider should store the cargo properties in state and expose them through the context API

Comment: @JMadelaine that is a good point. I think I am finding myself trouble trying to apply OO in functional programing. Sorry, fairly new to ReactJs and Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with complex state like that it is best to use `useReducer`. To go along with your cargos example it would like something like

```
interface CargoState {
    orders: Map<string, Products[]>;
    totalValue: number;
    totalNumber: number;
}

const cargoReducer = (state: CargoState, action): CargoState => {
   switch (action.type) {
       case 'add-product': {
           const newOrders = state.orders;
           newOrders.get(action.product.name).push(action.product);

           return {
               ...state,
               orders: newOrders,
               totalValue: state.totalValue + product.value,
               totalNumber: state.totalNumber++,
           }
       }
       default: return state;
    }
}



const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cargoReducer, [some initial state here]);


dispatch({ type: 'add-product', product });
```

The actions can be typed properly so you are not losing any typing.

Comment: Thank you @topchd. This is a great solution!